# Esp32 read lines from text file as strings get wrong worder

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

I have a text file test1.txt:

```
    aaa|aaa|aaa
    bbb|bbb|bbb
    ccc|ccc|ccc
    ddd|ddd|ddd
```

File has 4 rows as you can see. I use this code to read the content of the file and get each line as a separated string:

```cpp
#include "SPIFFS.h"
    
String file_content = "";
char VALUE [1024] = {'\0'};
     
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  if (!SPIFFS.begin(true)) {
    Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
    return;
  }
    
  File file = SPIFFS.open("/test1.txt");
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
    return;
  }

  uint16_t i = 0;

  while (file.available()) {
    VALUE[i] = file.read();
    Serial.println (VALUE[i]);
    i++;
  }
  VALUE[i] ='\0';
      
  Serial.println("Raw print");
  Serial.println (VALUE); //use for debug
  Serial.println("String print");
  String myString = String(VALUE);
  Serial.println (myString);
        
  file.close();
    
  int delimiter, delimiter_1, delimiter_2, delimiter_3, delimiter_4;
  delimiter = myString.indexOf("\n");
  delimiter_1 = myString.indexOf("\n", delimiter + 1);
  delimiter_2 = myString.indexOf("\n", delimiter_1 +1);
  delimiter_3 = myString.indexOf("\n", delimiter_2 +1);
  delimiter_4 = myString.indexOf("\n", delimiter_3 +1);
    
  // Define variables to be executed on the code later by collecting information from the readString as substrings.
  String row1 = myString.substring(delimiter + 1, delimiter_1);
  String row2 = myString.substring(delimiter_1 + 1, delimiter_2);
  String row3 = myString.substring(delimiter_2 + 1, delimiter_3);
  String row4 = myString.substring(delimiter_3 + 1, delimiter_4);
   
  Serial.println("Rows print");
  Serial.println(row1);
  Serial.println(row2);
  Serial.println(row3);
  Serial.println(row4);
}
    
void loop() {}
```

Output of Rows print is:

```
Rows print

bbb|bbb|bbb

ccc|ccc|ccc

ddd|ddd|ddd

aaa|aaa|aaa
```

Why is the "aaa" row thelast one and not first one? Basically delimiter_1 is "bbb" row instead be "aaa" row, and delimiter_4 is "aaa" row instead "ddd" row.

Thanks.

Comment: you print the content of the file 3 times. it can't be the complete output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <SPIFFS.h>

using namespace std;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (!SPIFFS.begin(true)) {
    Serial.println("An Error has occurred while mounting SPIFFS");
    return;
  }

  File file = SPIFFS.open("/test1.txt");
  if (!file) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open file for reading");
    return;
  }

  vector<String> v;
  while (file.available()) {
    v.push_back(file.readStringUntil('\n'));
  }
  file.close();

  for (String s : v) {
    Serial.println(s);
  }
}

void loop() {}
```

Output:

```
aaa|aaa|aaa
bbb|bbb|bbb
ccc|ccc|ccc
ddd|ddd|ddd
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to manipulate individual element, you could use regular for-loop iteration. See example below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
  Serial.println(v[i]);
}
```

Comment: Is working, but how can I assign each "s" to a separate variable ? like row,2,3 ?

Comment: @lucian_v For simplicity, I used range-based for loop to print the result. However, you can use regular for loop as well. i'll edit my answer.